# Pandas error: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in my **.txt** file as below:

```
029070 ***** 190101010600 270 36 OVC ** 0.0 ** **
```

I want to extract 190101 from the column 3, I am getting **AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandasbelow is my python pandas**. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re

data = pd.read_csv('dummy.txt', sep=" ", low_memory=False, header=None)
data.columns = ["a", "b", "c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j"]

print(data.c.str[0:6])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object\_ dtype in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje)

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that when you read your txt file, in it is casting "c" as an integer and the .str accessor will not work with non-string dtypes, you can fix this problem a couple of ways:

#### Option 1

Cast the integer as a string in the print statement.

```
print(data.c.astype(str).str[0:6])

0    190101
Name: c, dtype: object
```

#### Option 2

Cast as a string on the into the dataframe with `dtype` parameter in `read_csv`

```
data = pd.read_csv(txtfile, sep=' ', header=None, dtype={2:'str'})
data.columns = list('abcdefghij')
print(data.c.str[0:6]

0    190101
Name: c, dtype: object
```