# Pandas Can Only use .str access with string values

Tags: python, pandas

I have checked the following for help with this before posting:
[converting to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692532/pandas-error-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values) and
[null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48958708/pandas-error-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-object)

I do not have any null values, from what I can tell.

In order to check for null values, I did this:

```
null_columns = df_every_page.columns[df_every_page.isnull().any()]
print(df_every_page[df_every_page.isnull().any(axis=1)][null_columns].head())
```

This is what came back:

```
0    object
dtype:  object
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

Before looking for null values, I did `print(df_every_page)` to make sure it was not an empty column. There are values in this column.

Any suggestions?

**Edit #1:**

The exact error message I am getting is this:

> Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_
>   dtype in pandas

I am trying to grab literally everything out of a PDF document using tabula.

My data frame is literally just 1 column. The column name is called "everything".

**Edit #2:**

The command that I am running that leads me to this error is this:

```
df_search = 
df_every_page[df_every_page.everything.str.match('(Page.*)').str.len() > 0]
```

Sample of my data frame:

```
             everything

0            Invoice Name
1            Test Company
2            Oliver 1200
3            Address: 123 Fake Street
4            Invoice Number 123 abc
5            Date December 15th 2017
6            account number ####### / ######
7            Page 1 out of 10
```

**Edit #3**

My ultimate goal is to take everything from the PDF, throw it into 1 column using `tabula`.

I am then going to search all of the records to find any rows that have "page number" on them.

I am then going to throw those records into an array, strip the text part off of the values, and then use the page numbers to do something else that I do not have in my code yet.

I am using some regex to try and find these page number values, and that is where the error is coming from.

**Edit #4:**

If I had to guess, I'm going to say it has something to do with what I found [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11573):

**Edit #5:**

When I do `print(df_every_page.dtypes)` I get this:

```
everything   object
dtype:  object
```

**Edit #6:**

This is interesting.

I tried doing this:

```
df_every_page = pd.read_csv('./tmp_every_page.csv', dtype=object, encoding='utf-8', header=None)

df_every_page['everything'] = df_every_page.everything.astype(str).str.len()
```

And I got this error message:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa4' in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Even though the data type says object, I tried to convert it into a string anyway.

I wonder if this is what the problem could be, that is causing my regex not to work.

**Edit #7:**

The file I am working with actually has data that is in the "Dutch" language.

Euro signs, €, are in the data and being replaced with ¤.  I'm 99% certain this is what is screwing it up.

I tried replacing that value, but of course that doesn't work because of encoding.

I need to somehow replace that character with the euro sign, or replace it with nothing.

Utf-8 does not seem to work for character encoding. I tried setting up iso8859-9 but that didn't work either. If we figure this out, I think that should solve everything.

Comment: What does your DataFrame look like?

Comment: Where are you even trying to use the string accessor here?  Are you getting an error? What does your dataframe look like?

Comment: I edited my post to answer your questions.

Comment: Post a sample of your dataframe, and the command you are trying to use

Comment: Done, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: What if you convert it to type string? df_every_page = df_every_page.astype(str) ?

Comment: I just edited my post. See edit #6

Comment: I think it has something to do with some of the characters, see edit #7

Comment: does  `df_every_page['everything'].fillna("").str.len()` error out? if yes, can you edit post with the traceback?

Comment: Nope, there was no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ultimate goal was to extract all of the text from a pdf document into 1 column in a pandas data frame.

I then wanted to search this entire column for words that looked like "Page 1 of whatever" in each row.

My original solution was to try and use regular expressions; however, this is where I started having problems.

What I eventually ended up doing was this:

What I did was use the Pandas to filter for those rows. I then threw those rows into a list, and used that to find the mage page number.

I am going to use the max page number to tell tabula how many pages exist. Instead of using all, I am iterating 1 page at a time, for performance reasons, and because it is easier to format vs doing them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing any of your operations, try

> df_every_page = df_every_page.fillna(‘’)

Or if only some of the columns are strings

> > df_every_page [[‘col1’, ‘col2’]]= df_every_page [[‘col1’, ‘col2’]].fillna(‘’)

Comment: Thanks though! I think it has something to do with my data type, see "edit #4"

Comment: I only have 1 column, there are no other columns.