# AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Str.replace method returns an attribute error.

```
dc_listings['price'].str.replace(',', '')
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas
```

Here are the top 5 rows of my price column.

```
In [122]: dc_listings['price'].head()
Out[122]:
577     185.0
2166    180.0
3631    175.0
71      128.0
1011    115.0
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

This stack overflow [thread recommends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33692532/pandas-error-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values) to check if my column has NAN values but non of the values in my column are NAN.

```
In [130]: dc_listings[dc_listings['price'].isnull()]
Out[130]:
 host_response_rate host_acceptance_rate ... price cleaning_fee security_deposit
```

Comment: Your column is a `float`, so you can't use the string methods on it. Also, since it's a float column, it won't have `','` in it.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

As the error states, you can only use `.str` with string columns, and you have a `float64`. There won't be any commas in a float, so what you have won't really do anything, but in general, you could cast it first:

```
dc_listings['price'].astype(str).str.replace...
```

For example:

```
In [18]: df
Out[18]:
          a         b         c         d         e
0  0.645821  0.152197  0.006956  0.600317  0.239679
1  0.865723  0.176842  0.226092  0.416990  0.290406
2  0.046243  0.931584  0.020109  0.374653  0.631048
3  0.544111  0.967388  0.526613  0.794931  0.066736
4  0.528742  0.670885  0.998077  0.293623  0.351879

In [19]: df['a'].astype(str).str.replace("5", " hi ")
Out[19]:
0    0.64 hi 8208 hi  hi 4779467
1          0.86 hi 7231174332336
2            0.04624337481411367
3       0. hi 44111244991 hi 194
4          0. hi 287421814241892
Name: a, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 15):

Two ways:

1. You can use `series` to fix this error.

   ```
   dc_listings['price'].series.str.replace(',', '')
   ```

---

2. And if `series` doesn't work you can also alteratively use `apply(str)` as shown below:

   ```
   dc_listings['price'].apply(str).str.replace(',', '')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[Randy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5224926/randy) has the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52065957/19774945) to handle your problem with changing the whole column into `str` type. But when you have `non-str-type` value (like **NA**, **list**, **dict**, a **custom class**) inside that column and wanted to **filter** those **special values** in the future, i suggest you create your own function and then `apply` it to the `str value` only, like this:

```
dc_listings['price'] = dc_listings['price'].apply(
   lambda x: x.replace(',', '') if type(x) is str else x
)
```

or more clearly, using `def` :

```
def replace_substring_or_return_value(value):
  if type(value) is str: return x.replace(',', '')
  else: return value

dc_listings['price'] = dc_listings['price'].apply(
      replace_substring_or_return_value
)
```

**ALTHOUGH** this might be a bad practice, because you should use **`the same data type`** for every value in a column

Answer (score -1):

first step is convert a numerical values (like int,float) to string values (like object) after you can perform a function.

For example...

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype("int/float").astype('str')
```

After this step you can perform a any string functions...

Comment: `.astype("int/float")` ???

Answer (score -2):

If price is a dtype float 64 then the data is not a string.
You can try `dc_listings['price'].apply(function)`

Comment: What's `function`?