# Split strings from a pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
            df 

                          Scenario    Savings             PC1    PC2
                     0     HI        Total_FFC_base0      0.12    0.13
                     1     HI        Total_FFC_savings1   0.15    0.12
                     2     HI        Total_FFC_savings2   0.12    0.14
                     3     HI        Total_FFC_savings3   0.17    0.15
                     4     HI        Total_site_base0     0.12    0.15
                     5     HI        Total_site_savings1  0.15    0.15
```

I want to replace df.Savings and created another column df['EL'] by extracting some of the string form column 'Savings, so the df looks like this:

```
            df 

                          Scenario    Savings    EL         PC1    PC2
                     0     HI          FFC       0         0.12    0.13
                     1     HI          FFC       1         0.15    0.12
                     2     HI          FFC       2         0.12    0.14
                     3     HI          FFC       3         0.17    0.15
                     4     HI          site      0         0.12    0.15
                     5     HI          site      1         0.15    0.15
```

I used the following code to replace df['Savings].

```
       df['Saving']=df['Savings'].str.split('_')[1]
```

However, I got the following error message.

"Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: it should be df['Savings'].str.split('_').str[1]

Comment: Thank you! It worked.

Comment: Please share the entire error message. The formatting of your post is broken, by the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object\_ dtype in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Scenario':['HI','HI','HI','HI','HI','HI'],
                   'Savings':['Total_FFC_base0','Total_FFC_savings1','Total_FFC_saving2',
                              'Total_FFC_savings3','Total_site_base0','Total_site_savings1'],
                    'PC1':[0.12,0.15,0.12,0.17,0.12,0.15],
                    'PC2':[0.13,0.12,0.14,0.15,0.15,0.15]})
df['Saving'] = df['Savings'].str.split('_').apply(lambda x: x[1])
df['EL'] = df['Savings'].str.extract('(\d+)') #To extract only digits
df = df.drop(columns='Savings')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Scenario Saving   PC1   PC2 EL
0       HI    FFC  0.12  0.13  0
1       HI    FFC  0.15  0.12  1
2       HI    FFC  0.12  0.14  2
3       HI    FFC  0.17  0.15  3
4       HI   site  0.12  0.15  0
5       HI   site  0.15  0.15  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Perfect usecase for `named groups` with `regex`, we can extract the data and simultaneously name the columns:

```
df[['Savings', 'EL']] = df['Savings'].str.extract('_(?P<Savings>.*)_.*(?P<EL>\d+)')

  Scenario Savings   PC1   PC2 EL
0       HI     FFC  0.12  0.13  0
1       HI     FFC  0.15  0.12  1
2       HI     FFC  0.12  0.14  2
3       HI     FFC  0.17  0.15  3
4       HI    site  0.12  0.15  0
5       HI    site  0.15  0.15  1
```

Answer (score 0):

In python split() function which takes a parameter to separate the values here you use ('_') underscore and when you splitting the string you give index[1].that's why it use FFC So if you see on index 1 after underscore FFC is present.and in pandas object is complex dtype.