# Python script for protein databases that works in OSX and raspbian is not working in Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, ubuntu

My python script for some reason is working in MAC OSX, and in raspbian buster (Yes, I tried it in a raspberry in a moment of desperation) but it is not working in Ubuntu 18 SO That I use in my main PC. I have even tried a fresh install of Ubuntu Mate 20 in other PC, but it is still not working.

This is the script:

```
import sys
import csv
from http.client import IncompleteRead
import pandas as pd
from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = ""

    

# get from WPs accession, corresponding assembly, NC IDs, strains names. Write a csv table with all these as final data tablee,
#+ a table with WPs and Assembly IDs for inputting in FLAG

list_of_accession = []
with open (sys.argv[1], 'r') as csvfile:
    efetchin=csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in efetchin:
        list_of_accession.append(str(row[0]))
        
with open('efetch_output.txt', mode = 'w') as efetch_output:
    efetch_output = csv.writer(efetch_output, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    efetch_output.writerow(['ID','Source', 'Nucleotide Accession', 'Start', 'Stop', 'Strand', 'Protein', 'Protein Name', 'Organism', ' Strain', 'Assembly'])

input_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="protein", id= list_of_accession, rettype="ipg", retmode="tsv")
for line in input_handle:
    print(line, file=open('efetch_output.txt','a'))
input_handle.close()
#process file in pandas
file_name = "efetch_output.txt"
file_name_output = "final_output.tsv"
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, sep="\t", low_memory=False)
# Get names of indexes for which rows have to be dropped
indexNames = df[ df['Source'] == 'INSDC'].index
# Delete these row indexes from dataFrame
df.drop(indexNames , inplace=True)
#rearrange table columns
df = df[['ID', 'Source', 'Nucleotide Accession', 'Protein', 'Protein Name', 'Start', 'Stop', 'Strand', 'Organism',' Strain', 'Assembly']]
#Sort table on Assembly number ignoring GCF_
df['sort'] = df['Assembly'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(str)
df.sort_values('sort',inplace=True, ascending=True)
df = df.drop('sort', axis=1)
#drop all duplicates that're similar in indicated subset fields
df3=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Start', 'Stop', 'Strand', 'Organism',' Strain', 'Assembly'],keep='first')
#sorts dataframe alphabetically by Organism and writes to csv
df3.sort_values(by = "Organism", axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False).to_csv("final_parsed_output.tsv", "\t", index=False)
#get WP_X and GFC_X IDs in a tsv to input in FLAGs
new_dataframe1 = df3[['Assembly', 'Protein']]
new_dataframe2 = df3[['Organism',' Strain', 'Assembly', 'Protein']]
new_dataframe1.sort_values(by = "Protein", axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False).to_csv('flags_input.tsv', '\t', header=False, columns = ['Assembly', 'Protein'])
new_dataframe2.sort_values(by = "Organism", axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False).to_csv('flags_input_wstrains.tsv', '\t', header=False, columns = ['Organism',' Strain', 'Assembly', 'Protein'])





print ('program finished')
```

I do not know if I can upload here a csv as an example that you can use. But they are basically a list of proteins in a csv like this:

> WP_047566605.1 WP_043586512.1 WP_086526429.1 WP_043669791.1
> WP_086513259.1 WP_086518190.1 WP_053774664.1 WP_012298127.1
> WP_063071144.1 WP_012038522.1 WP_066595335.1 WP_088456184.1
> WP_058743206.1 WP_042537210.1 WP_058724426.1

The error that I got in ubuntu mate 20 is:

```
jj@p4:~/Documents/Bioinformatica/Bioinformatic/August/Codes/Etna$ python3 etna.py JJTEST.csv 
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:68: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return op(a, b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "etna.py", line 44, in <module>
    df['sort'] = df['Assembly'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(str)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 5126, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/accessor.py", line 187, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2100, in __init__
    self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/strings.py", line 2157, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!
```

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje

Comment: I have tried change line 44 to

 `df['sort'] = df['Assembly'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(float)`  

  and the new error is: 

`/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/core/computation/expressions.py:68: FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison
  return op(a, b)
program finished`


Same error if I do: `df['sort'] = df['Assembly'].astype(str).str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False).astype(str)`

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. Next time, please first extract a [mcve] to become part of your question. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I thought that including the quote of WP_numbers would be enough as a minimal reproducible example. I do not know how to upload a CSV file.  The code was also the minimum possible. I am sorry if I did not make a correct question, I tried to follow all rules. I can delete the post if it is not OK.

Comment: You could put the data inline into the Python code, no need for a second file. Also, any line after the line that throws the error is irrelevant for the example. You need to check if any other code can be removed or simplified as well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand fully what was the problem, but I have modified the output files from txt to csv, and change de tsv str to float.  Now it is working.