# deleting all specifics characters from xlsx file with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I need to delete all the ; and ' from a xlsx file I am working with, I've been trying to use pandas for it but it is not quite working, my code looks like this

```
import pandas

path = r"C:\Users\gb2gaet\Nova pasta\data.xlsx"

df= pandas.read_excel(path)

for column in df.columns:
    df[column] = df[column].replace(';', "")


df.to_excel("new.xlsx")
```

I've done this before but with numerical values and it worked just fine, but when I run this piece of code and then I go check at the file it still has the unwanted ;
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[pandas.Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html#pandas-series-str-replace)

```py
df[column] = df[column].str.replace(';', "")
```

Comment: i get this error message:  Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje

Comment: Or limit your replace to the string columns and not to all columns.