# Locating certain numbers in column rows for example 123456789 in column Pan if i want to locat rows that contain 1234

Tags: python, pandas

guys this drives me crazy i tried every thing
if i got for example a row called Pan and contains 10 rows and there are 5 rows begin with 1234
what do i do to filter only those rows of 1234
how to get rows contains only 010 or 9000 in the below column

```
Pan
90001041673
90001036780
90001036780
90001036780
```

the column was int64 and i changed it to object and also changed it to a string and i always get this error when executing

```
df['Pan'].str.contains("9000")
```

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: cant use this df['Pan'].str.contains

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a numeric column as a string column, try: `df['Pan'].astype(str).str.contains("9000")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object\_ dtype in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to access a numeric column as a string column, try: df['Pan'].astype(str).str.contains("9000")