# Drop rows that contain a specific string in a column

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, drop

I have a large pandas dataset in the format as below

```
col1
11111112322
15211114821
25482136522
45225625656
11125648121
```

I would like to drop all rows that contain 1111 (four consecutive ones) to have below results

```
25482136522
45225625656
11125648121
```

I tried this but did not work:

```
data = df[df["col1"].str.contains("1111")==False]
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    data1_1 = section1[section1["col1"].str.contains("111111")==False]
  File "C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5575, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
  File "C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\accessor.py", line 182, in __get__
    accessor_obj = self._accessor(obj)
  File "C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 177, in __init__
    self._inferred_dtype = self._validate(data)
  File "C:\Users\henry\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\strings\accessor.py", line 231, in _validate
    raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?
```

Comment: Minor thing, but the traceback doesn't match the code. What you could do is run this code then post that error message. For reference, see [mre] and [Why post full errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object\_ dtype in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065909/attributeerror-can-only-use-str-accessor-with-string-values-which-use-np-obje)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue, is, as the error code states, that the column is not a column of strings:

> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!. Did you mean: 'std'?

So to perform string actions on it, you have to first convert the column to strings, then your code will work:

```
df[df["col1"].astype(str).str.contains("1111")==False]
```

Output:

```
          col1
2  25482136522
3  45225625656
4  11125648121
```